# When I am trying to create a index by using lucene for csv file, The CSV file contains two consecutive integers, The two cloumn's as one word

Tags: java, lucene

When I am trying to create a index by using lucene for csv file, The CSV file contains two consecutive integers, The two consecutive column considering as a one word while searching with a key word.

For example: In my csv file i have two column's like 123,456. While creating a index it's considering as a one word and file searching with 123 i am not getting the results. But while searching with 123,456 i am able to get the results.

Comment: what analizer do you use for indexing?  you need analizer which can extract your words by comma

Comment: First we are storing the CSV file data in the DB and by using the Blob.getBinaryStream() we are fetching the data and we converting it into inputStream. After that we are adding the data into new TextField(String, data, Field.Store.YES)  and after that we are converting that into org.apache.lucene.document.Document. We are using the basic Analizer org.apache.lucene.index in this class we are using this method.
public void addDocument(Iterable<? extends IndexableField> doc) throws IOException {
    addDocument(doc, analyzer);
  }

So we are using basic Analyizer.

Comment: The Lucene standard analyzer will tokenize `123,456` as a single token. If that comma is a CSV field separator, then you need the input string to be `123, 456` with a space after the comma. Or just `123 456` (no comma). But that starts to get very messy, if your CSV data fields can also contain commas. The safest thing to do is to **use a CSV parsing library** to split each CSV line into its separate fields _before_ you hand over the CSV data to Lucene. See [Open CSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), [Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) and other libraries.